# what should nodeJS/commonJS module.exports return

Tags: node.js, express, commonjs

I know that I can set `module.exports` to either an object or a function
(and in some cases a function that will return an object).

I am also aware of the differences and ways to use `exports` vs. `module.exports` so no need to comment on that.

I also understand that whatever is returned is cached and will be returned on any consecutive call to `require`. So that if I choose to return a function and not an object then possibly this implies that on every require It is necessary to actually run this function.

I was wondering is there any defacto standard on which of those two should be used.  Or if there is no such standard - what considerations would apply when deciding if my module should return an object, a function or anything more complicated...

The module I intend to write is expected to be used as part of an express application if it matters (maybe there is a "local defacto standard" for express/connect modules).

Answer (score 1):

If the `require`'d code is standalone, and does not need access to any objects from the parent code, I `export` an object.

*edit* - the above is my preferred way to do it. I do the below only when I need to pass stuff into the module, like configuration data, or my database object. I haven't found a more elegant way to give the module access to variables that are in the parents' scope.

So to pass an object from parent into module I use a function:

```
//parent.js
var config = { DBname:'bar' };
var child = require('./child.js')(config);

//child.js
module.exports = function(cfg){
  var innerchild = {};
  innerchild.blah = function(){
    console.log(cfg.DBname); // this is out of scope unless you pass it in
  }
  return innerchild;
};
```

Comment: Well said! This is pretty much the convention. Note how he is using the function just as a wrapper for generating an object that has instance-specific configuration.

Comment: Exactly, when `module.exports` is called, I assemble the `innerchild` object using the passed-in `cfg` then return the object. I would usually have several functions dangling off `innerchild` that use the object/objects I passed in.

Comment: would it not make sense to always use the function way so that if you decide at some later stage that you DO need to get some options/setup you will not break the API ? and also make it clearer that whenever you "require" something you need to run it. so you dont have with var `m=require('pathToModule');`  and `m=require('pathToModule')(conf);`  or maybe it would be even better to do something like `m=require('pathToModule').init(conf);`

Answer (score 0):

> "so that if I choose to return a function and not an object then
>   possibly this implies that on every require It is necessary to
>   actually run this function."

It does not matter whether you return an individual function or an object. In neither cases a function (or functions) are ran. unless you explicitly do so.

For instance, consider the a module `hello.js`:

```
exports = function () { return 'Hello'; };
```

You can use require to get that function:

```
var hello = require('hello');
```

If you want to run that function, you need to invoke it explicitly as follows:

```
var hello = require('hello')();
```

You wrote you want to make sure your function is executed exactly once. Intuitively this could lead you to writing your `hello.js` as follows:

```
var hello = function () { return 'Hello'; };
exports = hello();
```

In which case you could just store result from hello via require:

```
var hello = require('hello');
```

However: if you do that [the export system may cache your module](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching). In such cases, you do not get fresh result from hello, but instead, a cached value. This may or may not be what you want. If you want to make sure a function is invoked every time it is required, you need to export a function and call it after require.

Comment: I understand that returning a function does not mean that a call to require would run it but what would be the point in returning a function in that case? the code that required my module would most likely want to run the function (unless is in a code path that does not get executed).

Comment: Please read my Q again. It was about what is recommended/defacto standard to return from require.

Comment: The point is that returning a function and immediately executing it is the only way to ensure your function is ran exactly once every time its included. See the edit.

Comment: @jsalonen caching applies per node session AFAIK. If @epeleg only `requires` a module once when running their script; it should be executed exactly once. If you require it again, without restarting your script, then the caching comes into play

Comment: @Plato You are likely right. However, I wouldn't bet on that in the long run. You forgot about it, add some nice extra-caching module, and suddenly everything goes (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Comment: @Plato - actually as @jsalonen stated "the export system MAY cache your module" so you can not trust it to be cached... not only that but it also says here: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_caching_caveats  that `"Modules are cached based on their resolved filename. Since modules may resolve to a different filename based on the location of the calling module (loading from node_modules folders), it is not a guarantee that require('foo') will always return the exact same object, if it would resolve to different files."`